# Backup Windows Server 2003

Tags: администрирование, резервное-копирование, восстановление, клонирование

Есть на работе старик, сервер с ПО Windows Server 2003,он в работе постоянно, не выключается. Установить на него какое либо ПО для backUp не решаюсь, бо боюсь что слетят службы, или другое какое-либо ПО(було на других более современных ПО подобные ситуации) Перенести на другой ПК эти службы с тем же ПО не получается(но еще пытаюсь) Но тут начал сервак перегреваться уже,шумит. Время мало.
В нем есть внутренния программа для BackUP, она его делает в bkf формате.
А мне его нужно развернуть хотя бы на Hyper-V,бо другого сервера такого же нет.
А на другой ПК конфликт с драйверами думаю будет. 
Есть еще варианты,кто сталкивался, смогу ли развернуть на Hyper-V?

Answer (score 0):

Получилось перенести система с помощью встроенной утилиты backup на Windows Server 2003.

1. Обратить внимание на логи в конце бэкапа(так как я не обратил и не получилось сделать , так как не все компоненты Windows были забэкаплены) Внимательно смотерть что бы не было ошибок Windows и рабочих программ.
2. На новый ПК я установил Windows Server 2003, перенес бэкап, поставил полное восстановление,и папку Windows? все выполнялось в рантайме,после попросило перегрузить пк + надо самому разбить разделы как изначально были на хосте откуда делали бэкап
3. Проблема с Активацией Windows, так как новое железо(три дня на активацию,скачал кряк,пока не нашел лицензионный ключ от старой винды)
4. Проблема с драйверами, я устанавливал на современный ПК, что пришлось сетевые карты искать по XP,что бы поднялись.
   На сегодняшний день,работает без проблем, так как такое ПО 2003 года,развернуть без мануалки очень проблематично!
5. Может быть проблема бэкапа, так как работает программа и ее остановить бы на время выполнения, у меня так было с Mysql,но уже не на этом серваке,а на XP)

Хорошо подойдет, если нема запчастей на пк,они древние и если нельзя выключать дольше чем на час, мой бэкап занял 7 часов. в рантайме,проблем с работай баз данных и программ не было.